# How to reach :new value from sub-type in trigger

Tags: oracle, triggers

How can I count only these rows which have the same province of the insert?

```
create or replace trigger sequence_num_trigg before insert on Distributor for each row 
declare counter NUMBER;
BEGIN
select count(*) INTO counter from distributor where treat(address as distributor_address_ty).province = :new.treat(address as distributor_address_ty).province;
if counter != 0 then
:new.seq_no := 1 + counter;
else
:new.seq_no := 0;
END IF;
END;
```

I know this is the wrong part

```
where treat(address as distributor_address_ty).province = :new.treat(address as distributor_address_ty).province;
```

how to fix it?

Comment: Probably `treat(:new.address as distributor_address_ty).province`.

Comment: But you will get a mutating table error anyway with your approach. An insert changes data in the table by adding one or more rows. You cannot count rows in the same table in a trigger, because the result would not be deterministic. (I.e. with an insert inserting many rows the count may vary depending on the order in which the rows happen to get inserted.)

Answer (score 0):

Don't use a trigger. Instead, give each row a unique id using an identity column (or a sequence) and then use the `ROW_NUMBER` analytic function to generate `seq_no` when you query the table:

```sql
Create or replace type distributor_address_ty as object (
  province VARCHAR2(10)
) NOT FINAL;

create table distributor (
  id      NUMBER
          GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY,
  address distributor_address_ty
);
```

Then insert some sample data:

```
INSERT INTO distributor (address)
VALUES (distributor_address_ty('A'));

INSERT INTO distributor (address)
SELECT distributor_address_ty('A') FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT distributor_address_ty('B') FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT distributor_address_ty('A') FROM DUAL;
```

Then you can generate a `seq_no` using:

```
SELECT d.id,
       d.address.province,
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY d.address.province ORDER BY d.id) AS seq_no
FROM   distributor d;
```

Which outputs:

| ID | ADDRESS.PROVINCE | SEQ_NO |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | 1 |
| 2 | A | 2 |
| 4 | A | 3 |
| 3 | B | 1 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/WBDbuini)